# mod_rewrite relative path not working. RewriteBase required

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a simple .htaccess file in a directory to redirect all request from that directory to a script inside the same directory, but relative paths aren't working and I have to use `RewriteBase` or else it will not work.

Here's my setup,

Directory layout:

```
/ (web root)
|- index.html
|- hooks
   |- .htaccess
   |- server.py
```

when I make a request to `http://example.com/hooks/foo` I expect it to rewrite as `http://example.com/hooks/server.py/foo`

So here's my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hooks/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ server.py/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The above works fine. But if I remove the `RewriteBase /hooks/` line it does not.

What gives? Shouldn't it default to relative paths? Is there a configuration issue on my host? Is there any way to debug this?

Comment: When you remove `RewriteBase`, the URL it'll rewrite to would be: `http://example.com/hooks/foo/server.py/foo`

Comment: When `RewriteBase` is commented out, do you get 404 for `http://example.com/hooks/foo` ?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Oh that makes sense! 
But why is that? If foo isn't a valid directory

Comment: @anubhava yes it 404's

Comment: What's the exact 404 error message?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove RewriteBase:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ server.py/$1 [L,QSA]
```

So http://example.com/hooks/foo will request the link
http://example.com/hooks/server.py/hooks/foo

I think that's the reason why you got an 404 error.

How about this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^hooks/(.*)$ server.py/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That's just a different way to write the same thing. I'm trying to remove the need to specify the current directory.